# HTML CSS Text hover linear-gradient transition fade

Tags: css, css-transitions, linear-gradients

In HTML/CSS I need to make some text, default the color is white.

But on hover I need to make it fade into gradient color.
I am using the next code:

CSS:

```
.a {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, white);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: 2s; /* Safari */
  transition: 2s;
}
.a:hover {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, #eee);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: 2s; /* Safari */
  transition: 2s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="a">SOME TEXT</div>
```

But on hover the color is changed right away without transition. Any help on this?

Comment: That is a question about background, this is question about Text color.

Comment: you used background to color the text so this question is also about background

Comment: But I am using background property to make gradient effect on text, because I am trimming it. But ok.